# Comparing the basicity of aniline and ortho anisidine

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

In  my worksheet there is a question that asks for the comparison of basicities of the three anisidine isomers and aniline:

[image]

After my analysis using:

$\text{Basicity} \propto \text{+M effect (except for meta annisidine)} \propto \dfrac{1}{\text{-I effect}}$,

I could make the following conclusions:

1. m-anisidine should be the least basic
2. p-anisidine should be more basic than aniline.

But the main problem is comparing the basicity of aniline and o-anisidine and comparing them with p-anisidine. I doubt the presence of [ortho effect](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases) in ortho isomer after seeing the [ball and stick model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-Anisidine#/media/File:O-Anisidine_3D_ball.png) which makes the interaction of lone pair of nitrogen with hydrogen atoms of $\ce{-OCH3}$ improbable.

The answer given is:

> p-anisidine> aniline > o-anisidine > m-anisidine (I have verified it with $pKa$ values from [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov))

Comment: I would say SIP.

Comment: But I want to think of it in terms of "tendency to donate **electrons**" @AvnishKabaj

Comment: Steric inhibition of protonation reduces the "tendency to donate electrons"

Answer (score 2):

**Why you considering the methyl group on $\ce{-OCH3}$ to be "locked" in position, facing away from the $\ce{-NH2}$ group?** It is free to rotate in all directions, and it *will* come at a position next to the $\ce{-NH2}$ group, where the ortho effect will apply.

For a visualization, here is a similar image:

[image]

(*taken from [Martin's excellent post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/89920/5026)*)

---

**PS:** I believe that Steric Inhibition of Resonance should not be invoked here, because *both* sides of the $\ce{-NH2}$ group are not blocked by the $\ce{-OCH3}$ group, and $\ce{-OCH3}$ is certainly not as bulky a group as *t*-butyl.

Comment: Nice! So basically in ortho effect here, hydrogen bond will be formed between the hydrogen of NH2 and O?

Comment: Nope, that way the lone pair of nitrogen is still free. The interaction will be between N of NH2 and H of OCH3 (also [see](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases#comment11214_7685))